# C++: Program does not seem to work when bitset arrays are used (correctly!) in place of bitset variables

Tags: c++, debugging, bitset

I have a very peculiar issue debugging some code. In the first iteration of this program, I used several bitset variables as opposed to making a single bitset array.

I am trying to figure out why the array only works for the very first case of anything, and not the rest (the output is a series of images)

Please note that it did work fine when the variables were used.

Any input at all would be appreciated. Essentially the trouble comes from either the bmp_split function or the save_bmp function, but my money is on the latter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

char *file_name = "grayImage.bmp";
#define X 1024
#define Y 768
#define N X*Y

//Function prototypes
FILE* load_bmp(char *fname);
BITMAPFILEHEADER read_header(FILE *f_ptr);
BITMAPINFOHEADER read_info(FILE *f_ptr);
BYTE* read_imagedata(FILE *f_ptr, BITMAPFILEHEADER *h_ptr);
void  new_split(BYTE* pixel, bitset<N> planes[]);
void bmp_split(BYTE *pixel, bitset<N> *p1, bitset<N> *p2, bitset<N> *p3, 
    bitset<N> *p4, bitset<N> *p5, bitset<N> *p6, bitset<N> *p7, bitset<N> *p8);
BITMAPFILEHEADER create_header();
BITMAPINFOHEADER create_info(BITMAPINFOHEADER *i_ptr);
RGBQUAD create_palette(BYTE R, BYTE G, BYTE B);
void save_bmp(char *fname, BITMAPFILEHEADER *header, BITMAPINFOHEADER *info, 
    std::bitset<N> *image);
unsigned char char_converter(std::bitset<8> *bin);
unsigned char *pack(std::bitset<N> *bin_plane);
string converInt(int number);


int main()
{
    /* bitset array */
        bitset<N> * plane_holder[8]; 

        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        {
            plane_holder[i] = new bitset<N>;
        }


        bitset<N> plane1;
        bitset<N> plane2;
        bitset<N> plane3;
        bitset<N> plane4;
        bitset<N> plane5;
        bitset<N> plane6;
        bitset<N> plane7;
        bitset<N> plane8;

        FILE *bmp_ptr;
        BITMAPFILEHEADER header_ptr, new_header;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER info_ptr, new_info;
        RGBQUAD new_palette1, new_palette2;
        BYTE *image_ptr;

        /*unsigned char pointer array replacing 8 char variables!
        unsigned char * buffer[8];*/
        unsigned char *buf1, *buf2, *buf3, *buf4, *buf5, *buf6, *buf7, *buf8;

        
        //Load the input 8bpp image
        cout << file_name << endl;
        //system("PAUSE");
        bmp_ptr = load_bmp(file_name);
        header_ptr = read_header(bmp_ptr); 
        info_ptr = read_info(bmp_ptr);
        if(info_ptr.biBitCount != 8)
        {
                cout << "This program is only for 8bpp images" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                return 0;
        }
        image_ptr = read_imagedata(bmp_ptr, &header_ptr);
        fclose(bmp_ptr);

        //Split the 8bpp image into eight 1bpp images
        //new_split(image_ptr, plane_holder);

       bmp_split(image_ptr, plane_holder[0], plane_holder[1], plane_holder[2], plane_holder[3], plane_holder[4], 
                plane_holder[5], plane_holder[6], plane_holder[7]);


        delete[] image_ptr;
        
        //Saving the planes
        new_header = create_header();
        new_info = create_info(&info_ptr);
        
        save_bmp("Picture1.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[0]);
        save_bmp("Picture2.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[1]);
        save_bmp("Picture3.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[2]);
        save_bmp("Picture4.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[3]);
        save_bmp("Picture5.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[4]);
        save_bmp("Picture6.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[5]);
        save_bmp("Picture7.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[6]);
        save_bmp("Picture8.bmp", &new_header, &new_info, plane_holder[7]);
        
        //Pack the eight 1bpp images

        
        buf1 = pack(plane_holder[0]);
        buf2 = pack(plane_holder[1]);
        buf3 = pack(plane_holder[2]);
        buf4 = pack(plane_holder[3]);
        buf5 = pack(plane_holder[4]);
        buf6 = pack(plane_holder[5]);
        buf7 = pack(plane_holder[6]);
        buf8 = pack(plane_holder[7]);
        
       
        delete[] buf1;
        delete[] buf2;
        delete[] buf3;
        delete[] buf4;
        delete[] buf5;
        delete[] buf6;
        delete[] buf7;
        delete[] buf8;

        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
        {
            delete plane_holder[i];
        }
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
}

/*  This function downloads a bmp file. The parameter is the name of the 
    bmp file. Returns the pointer to the bmp file.
*/
FILE* load_bmp(char *fname)
{
    FILE *bmp;  
    bmp=fopen(fname, "rb");
    if(bmp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "File opening fail\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    return bmp;
}

/*  This function reads the info header in the input bmp. The parameter is 
    the pointer to the input bmp. Returns pointer to the file header of the 
    input bmp.
*/
BITMAPFILEHEADER read_header(FILE *f_ptr)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    fread(&bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f_ptr);
    return bmfh;
}

/*  This function reads the info header in the input bmp. The parameter is 
    the pointer to the input bmp. Returns pointer to the info header of the 
    input bmp.
*/
BITMAPINFOHEADER read_info(FILE *f_ptr)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
    fread(&bmih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, f_ptr);
    return bmih;
}


/*  This function reads the image array in the input bmp. The parameters are 
    two pointer to the input bmp and its file header. Returns pointer to 
    the images array o fthe input bmp.
*/
BYTE* read_imagedata(FILE *f_ptr, BITMAPFILEHEADER *h_ptr)
{
    DWORD size;
    BYTE *tempPixelData;
    size = (*h_ptr).bfSize - (*h_ptr).bfOffBits;
    tempPixelData = new BYTE[size];
    if(tempPixelData == NULL) 
    {
        fclose(f_ptr);
        cout << "image extraction fail\n";
        return 0;
    }
    fread(tempPixelData,sizeof(BYTE),size,f_ptr);
    return tempPixelData;
}

/*  This function splits each pixel in the original 8bpp bmp into eight bits and 
    appends each bit to different bitset arrays. The parameters are the image array 
    of the original bmp, and eight bitset arrays which represents eight bitplanes.
*/

void bmp_split(BYTE *pixel, bitset<N> *p1, bitset<N> *p2, bitset<N> *p3, 
    bitset<N> *p4, bitset<N> *p5, bitset<N> *p6, bitset<N> *p7, bitset<N> *p8)
{
    int i, dec;
    BYTE *temp = pixel;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        dec = (int)*temp;
        (*p1)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p2)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p3)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p4)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p5)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p6)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p7)[i] = dec % 2;
        dec /= 2;
        (*p8)[i] = dec % 2;
        temp++;
    }
}

void new_split(BYTE* pixel, bitset<N> planes[])
{
    int i, dec; 
    BYTE *temp = pixel;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        dec = (int)*temp;
        planes[0][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[1][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[2][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[3][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[4][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[5][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[6][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        planes[7][i] = dec%2;
        dec /= 2;
        temp++;
    }


}

/*  This function creates an file header for a 1bpp bmp file. 
    All the features corresponds to the original 8bpp bmp file except for bpp.
    Returns the file header.
*/
BITMAPFILEHEADER create_header()
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
    header.bfType = 'B'+('M' << 8);
    header.bfReserved1 = 0;
    header.bfReserved2 = 0;
    header.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
        sizeof(RGBQUAD)*2;
    header.bfSize = header.bfOffBits + N/8;
    return header;
}

/*  This function creates an info header for a 1bpp bmp file. 
    All the features corresponds to the original 8bpp bmp file except for bpp.
    Returns the info header.
*/
BITMAPINFOHEADER create_info(BITMAPINFOHEADER *i_ptr)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
    info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.biWidth = X;
    info.biHeight = Y;
    info.biPlanes = 1;
    info.biBitCount = 1;
    info.biCompression = 0;
    info.biSizeImage = X*Y/8;
    info.biXPelsPerMeter = (*i_ptr).biXPelsPerMeter;
    info.biYPelsPerMeter = (*i_ptr).biYPelsPerMeter;
    info.biClrUsed = 0;
    info.biClrImportant = 0;
    return info;
}

/*  This function creates colour definition.
    The parameters are the degree of red, green, and blue.
    Returns the colour definition.
*/
RGBQUAD create_palette(BYTE R, BYTE G, BYTE B)
{
    RGBQUAD palette;
    palette.rgbBlue = R;
    palette.rgbGreen = G;
    palette.rgbRed = B;
    return palette;
}
/*  This function saves a pure black and white bitmap file of 1bpp.  
    The parameters are the desired file name, file header, info header, 
    and the image array.  
*/
void save_bmp(char *fname, BITMAPFILEHEADER *header, BITMAPINFOHEADER *info,
    std::bitset<N> *image)
{
    FILE *file_ptr = fopen(fname, "wb");
    fwrite(header, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, file_ptr);
    fwrite(info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, file_ptr);  
    fwrite(&create_palette(0,0,0), sizeof(RGBQUAD), 1, file_ptr);  
    fwrite(&create_palette(255,255,255), sizeof(RGBQUAD), 1, file_ptr);  
    fwrite(image, N, 1, file_ptr);
    fclose(file_ptr);
}

/*  This function converts a 8 digit binary number into a decimal number. 
    Given bitset of size 8, it returns single unsigned char variable.  
*/
unsigned char char_converter(bitset<8> *bin)
{
    int c = 0;
    c = (*bin)[7]*128+(*bin)[6]*64+(*bin)[5]*32+(*bin)[4]*16+(*bin)[3]*8
        +(*bin)[2]*4+(*bin)[1]*2+(*bin)[0]*1;
    return (unsigned char)c;
}

/*  This function packs 8 consecutive elements of 1bpp image array, 
    which represents 8 digit binary number into array of decimal 
    number of type unsigned char. Returns dynamically allocated 
    unsigned char array of size N/8. 
*/
unsigned char *pack(bitset<N> *bin_plane)
{
    bitset<8> bin;
    int i = N-1, j = 7, k = 0;
    unsigned char c, *buffer;
    buffer = new unsigned char[N/8];
    while(i>=0)
    {
        bin[j] = (*bin_plane)[i];
        if(j == 0)
        {
            j = 8;
            c = char_converter(&bin);
            buffer[k] = c;
            k++;
        }
        --i;
        --j;
    }
    return buffer;
}
string convertInt (int number)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss<<number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: -1: This is way too much code for a good SO question. Reduce the code to the bare minimum that shows the problem.

Comment: is this really the minimum amount of code that produces this issue? Seems a bit bloated..

Comment: Posting bounty to keep the question from being closed isn't anywhere near as productive as learning to use a debugger and writing a minimal test case.

Comment: Point taken. I shall stare at this a bit longer, and try to reproduce the error minimally, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Louis93: Can you provide a link to an image that will get past the `This program is only for 8bpp images` message?

Comment: This code seems to work OK for me. When it doesn't work for you, what happens?

Comment: user3150252, here`s an image: http://i.imgur.com/FaPgq.png

Comment: @David : You should notice that only one or two of the outputs are valid image files.

Comment: The image you posted the link to is in PNG format, but your code assumes BMP format.

Comment: That was due to the conversion of the image hoster, right click, save as bmp

Comment: For what it's worth, all 8 of the images this produces for me display fine.

Comment: May be you could take a look at http://www.kalytta.com/bitmap.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand why you need to split an 8bpp image into a monocrome image, however if you change the save_bmp function to the following, it at least produces images that are "valid"

```
void save_bmp(char *fname, BITMAPFILEHEADER *header, BITMAPINFOHEADER *info, 
    std::bitset<N> *image) 
{ 
    FILE *file_ptr = fopen(fname, "wb"); 
    fwrite(header, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, file_ptr); 
    fwrite(info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, file_ptr);   
    fwrite(&create_palette(0,0,0), sizeof(RGBQUAD), 1, file_ptr);   
    fwrite(&create_palette(255,255,255), sizeof(RGBQUAD), 1, file_ptr);   

    //fwrite(image, N, 1, file_ptr); 
    unsigned char * b = pack(image);
    fwrite(b,N/8,1,file_ptr);
    delete[] b;

    fclose(file_ptr); 
}
```

std:bitset is an object and not a buffer. Since you already had a pack function which packs the bitset in to a buffer, it seemed natural to use that instead of attempting to write an object to a file.